# Convert my C# code to use reactive extensions

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, queue, system.reactive

I have a piece of code that marshals synchronizations. There are two types of sync's that need to happen, low priority (initiated by navigation events on a treeview) and high priority (initiated by an exclusive Synchronize from a context menu).

I use a Queue collection to keep track of the items to be Sync'd. With a high priority queue to be processed before items on the low priority. Also, I want to put a limit of say 20 or 30 items on the low priority queue.

So I wrote this code:

```
// Queue for high priority items.
Queue<SyncItem> syncQueueHighPriority = new Queue<SyncItem>();

// Queue for low priority items.
Queue<SyncItem> syncQueueLowPriority = new Queue<SyncItem>();

// Sync in progress flag.
Boolean syncInProgress = false;

public void SyncHighPriority(object data)
{
    // Add item to queue to be sync'd when ready.
    SyncItem item = new SyncItem { SyncPriority = Priority.High, SharePointListItem = data };
    syncQueueHighPriority.Enqueue(item);

    // Iniate a sync.
    ProcessSync();
}

public void SyncLowPriority(object data)
{
    // Add item to queue to be sync'd when ready if within the limit of the queue.
    SyncItem item = new SyncItem { SyncPriority = Priority.High, SharePointListItem = data };
    if (syncQueueLowPriority.Count < 20)
        syncQueueLowPriority.Enqueue(item);

    // Iniate a sync.
    ProcessSync();
}

private void ProcessSync()
{
    if (syncInProgress)
        return;

    SyncItem item = null;

    // The item will be set by a high priority sync before a low priority item.
    if (syncQueueHighPriority.Count > 0)
        item = syncQueueHighPriority.Dequeue();
    else
    {
        // Set low priority if there are no high priority items.
        if (syncQueueLowPriority.Count > 0)
            item = syncQueueHighPriority.Dequeue();
    }

    // If we have an item to sync, then sync it.
    if (item != null)
        Sync(item);
}

private void Sync(SyncItem itemToSync)
{
    syncInProgress = true;

    // Do sync operations.
    // SYNCSTUFF!

    syncInProgress = false;

    // then process the next item if one exists.
    ProcessSync();
}


// Data classes sample
public class SyncItem
{
    public Priority SyncPriority { get; set; }
    public object SharePointListItem { get; set; }
}

public enum Priority
{
    High = 1,
    Low = 0
}
```

I don't necessarily think this is the cleanest code because of the fact I have two queues to manage. I would like one collection essentially that always processes high priority items first and limits the amount of low priority items that can be queued.

From reading, I believe C# reactive extensions would be a much better way to approach this.  I'm a complete newbie to it though and it seems very complicated. I've read a few articles but not sure the best way to convert what I have to something that works how I need. Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to convert this to use reactive extensions?

Comment: You use this code in Multithread environment? You invoke `SyncHighPriority` and `SyncLowPriority` from multiple thread?

Comment: I'm using MVVM with WPF.  Both the sync types are initialized from the UI thread currently.

Comment: Are you sure your code is working the way you want?  In `SyncLowPriority1 you set the sync item's priority to `High`.  Also your `ProcessSync()` and `Sync()` method appear completely synchronous and are called everytime you add an item to the queue.  If you indeed always invoke from the UI thread then it is guaranteed that you block whenever you add an item to the queue until it is sync.  Thus your queues never have more than a single item in them at a time.  You might as well call `Sync` directly

Comment: Hi Brandon - you made a good point - I had a mistake where I had low priority set to high (edited) and the sync runs its code inside a Task.Start call.  The code above is just a pseudo outline of what's going on :-)